# How to use two different dropdowns to sort through two different data attributes?

Tags: javascript

I have a custom dropdown filter (not a **select > option** filter) and I am trying to sort by two different data attributes. I am able to sort by the **Story Type**, but I can't seem to get the **Year** to work.

Additionally, I can't seem to get the reset button working.

```js
//dropdown
for (const dropdown of document.querySelectorAll(".custom__select-wrapper")) {
  dropdown.addEventListener("click", function () {
    this.querySelector(".custom__select").classList.toggle("open");
  });
}

for (const option of document.querySelectorAll(".custom__option")) {
  option.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (!this.classList.contains("selected")) {
      this.parentNode
        .querySelector(".custom__option.selected")
        .classList.remove("selected");
      this.classList.add("selected");
      this.closest(".custom__select").querySelector(
        ".custom__select-trigger span"
      ).textContent = this.textContent;
      storyFilter(this.dataset["value"]);
    }
  });
}

for (const option of document.querySelectorAll(".custom__option")) {
  option.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (!this.classList.contains("selected")) {
      this.parentNode
        .querySelector(".custom__option.selected")
        .classList.remove("selected");
      this.classList.add("selected");
      this.closest(".custom__select").querySelector(
        ".custom__select-trigger span"
      ).textContent = this.textContent;
      yearFilter(this.dataset["year"]);
    }
  });
}

window.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  for (const select of document.querySelectorAll(".custom__select")) {
    if (!select.contains(e.target)) {
      select.classList.remove("open");
    }
  }
});

// filter
function storyFilter(className) {
  const list = document.querySelectorAll(".list.article");

  for (const article of list) {
    article.classList.add("hidden");
    if (article.getAttribute("data-story") === className) {
      article.classList.remove("hidden");
    }
  }
}

function yearFilter(className) {
  const list = document.querySelectorAll(".list.article");

  for (const article of list) {
    article.classList.add("hidden");
    if (article.getAttribute("data-year") === className) {
      article.classList.remove("hidden");
    }
  }
}

//reset button
let filterSelection = document.querySelector("#storyFilter");
filterSelection.addEventListener("change", function () {
  selectedFilter.classList.remove("hidden");
});

function clearSelection() {
  storyFilter.options[0].selected = "selected";
  yearFilter.options[0].selected = "selected";
  selectedFilter.classList.add("hidden");
  // reset articles
  [...document.querySelectorAll(".article")].forEach((article) =>
    article.classList.remove("hidden")
  );
}
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
/* Roboto Font */
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i,900,900i&display=swap");
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

button.clear {
  border: 0;
  background: #fff;
}



.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.custom__select {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.custom__select-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  user-select: none;
  width: 100%;
}
.custom__select-trigger {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 22px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #3b3b3b;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  background: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.custom__options {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  background-color: #005fec;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-top: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 2;
}
.custom__select.open .custom__options {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  pointer-events: all;
  color: #fff;
}
.custom__option {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 22px 0 28px;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
.custom__option:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #b2b2b2;
}
.custom__option.selected {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.custom__option.selected::before {
  content: "•";
  margin-left: -12px;
  padding-right: 8px;
}

/* arrow */
.arrow {
  position: relative;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
}
.arrow::before, .arrow::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 0.15rem;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
.arrow::before {
  left: -5px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background-color: #394a6d;
}
.arrow::after {
  left: 5px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  background-color: #394a6d;
}
.open .arrow::before {
  left: -5px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.open .arrow::after {
  left: 5px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.arrow::after {
  left: 5px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  background-color: #394a6d;
}
.open .arrow::before {
  left: -5px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.open .arrow::after {
  left: 5px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="custom__select-wrapper">
    <div class="custom__select">
      <div class="custom__select-trigger">
        <span>Story Type</span>
        <div class="arrow"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="custom__options" id="storyFilter">
        <span class="custom__option selected">All</span>
        <span class="custom__option" data-value="news">News and Media</span>
        <span class="custom__option" data-value="analysis">Analysis</span>
        <span class="custom__option" data-value="press">Press Releases</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="custom__select-wrapper">
    <div class="custom__select">
      <div class="custom__select-trigger"><span>Year</span>
        <div class="arrow"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="custom__options" id="yearFilter">
        <span class="custom__option selected">All</span>
        <span class="custom__option" data-year="2020">2020</span>
        <span class="custom__option" data-year="2019">2019</span>
        <span class="custom__option" data-year="2020">2018</span>
        <span class="custom__option" data-year="2019">2017</span>
        <span class="custom__option" data-year="2020">2016</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- reset button -->
<button class="clear hidden" id="selectedFilter" onclick="clearSelection()">clear filters</button>

<!-- articles -->
<div class="list article" data-year="2020" data-story="news">
  <ul>
    <li><strong>Company:</strong> Company 1</li>
    <li><strong>Start Date:</strong> March 26, 2020</li>
    <li><strong>Title:</strong> <a href="#" target="_blank">Article Title</a></li>
    <li><strong>Type:</strong> news</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="list article" data-year="2019" data-story="news">
  <ul>
    <li><strong>Company:</strong> Company 2</li>
    <li><strong>Start Date:</strong> November 17, 2019</li>
    <li><strong>Title:</strong> <a href="#" target="_blank">Article Title</a></li>
    <li><strong>Type:</strong> news</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="list article" data-year="2017" data-story="analysis">
  <ul>
    <li><strong>Company:</strong> Company 3</li>
    <li><strong>Start Date:</strong> March 15, 2018</li>
    <li><strong>Title:</strong> <a href="#" target="_blank">Article Title</a></li>
    <li><strong>Type:</strong> analysis</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="list article" data-year="2016" data-story="analysis">
  <ul>
    <li><strong>Company:</strong> Company 4</li>
    <li><strong>Start Date:</strong> January 3, 2017</li>
    <li><strong>Title:</strong> <a href="#" target="_blank">Article Title</a></li>
    <li><strong>Type:</strong> analysis</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="list article" data-year="2014" data-story="press">
  <ul>
    <li><strong>Company:</strong> Company 5</li>
    <li><strong>Start Date:</strong> March 13, 2016</li>
    <li><strong>Title:</strong> <a href="#" target="_blank">Aritcle Title</a></li>
    <li><strong>Type:</strong> press</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="list article" data-year="2013" data-story="press">
  <ul>
    <li><strong>Company:</strong> Company 6</li>
    <li><strong>Start Date:</strong> March 6, 2015</li>
    <li><strong>Title:</strong> <a href="#" target="_blank">Article Title</a></li>
    <li><strong>Type:</strong> press</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the other `custom__option` event listener because its not able to pass anything when I logged the value. The year is also passed as `dataset["year"]`. I added a `current_story` and `current_year` to filter those two when the other is selected. And your `data-year` is messed up I thought I was getting an error.

This is not the best implementation but it gets you going if you want to change some.

```js
//dropdown
var current_story = "",
  current_year = "";

for (const dropdown of document.querySelectorAll(".custom__select-wrapper")) {
  dropdown.addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.querySelector(".custom__select").classList.toggle("open");
  });
}

for (const option of document.querySelectorAll(".custom__option")) {
  option.addEventListener("click", function() {

    if (!this.classList.contains("selected")) {
      this.parentNode
        .querySelector(".custom__option.selected")
        .classList.remove("selected");
      this.classList.add("selected");
      this.closest(".custom__select").querySelector(
        ".custom__select-trigger span"
      ).textContent = this.textContent;
      if (this.getAttribute('data-year')) {
        current_year = this.dataset["year"];
        yearFilter(this.dataset["year"]);
      } else {
        current_story = this.dataset["value"];
        storyFilter(this.dataset["value"]);
      }

    }
  });
}

window.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  for (const select of document.querySelectorAll(".custom__select")) {
    if (!select.contains(e.target)) {
      select.classList.remove("open");
    }
  }
});

// filter
function storyFilter(className) {
  const list = document.querySelectorAll(".list.article");

  for (const article of list) {
    article.classList.add("hidden");
    if (article.getAttribute("data-story") === className) {
      if (current_year !== "" && article.getAttribute("data-year") === current_year) {
        article.classList.remove("hidden");
      } else if (current_year === "") {
        article.classList.remove("hidden");
      }
    }
  }
}

function yearFilter(className) {
  const list = document.querySelectorAll(".list.article");

  for (const article of list) {
    article.classList.add("hidden");
    if (article.getAttribute("data-year") == className) {
      if (current_story !== "" && article.getAttribute("data-story") === current_story) {
        article.classList.remove("hidden");
      } else if ((current_story === "")) {
        article.classList.remove("hidden");
      }
    }
  }
}

//reset button
let filterSelection = document.querySelector("#storyFilter");

filterSelection.addEventListener("change", function() {
  selectedFilter.classList.remove("hidden");
});

function clearSelection() {
  storyFilter.options[0].selected = "selected";
  yearFilter.options[0].selected = "selected";
  selectedFilter.classList.add("hidden");
  // reset articles
  [...document.querySelectorAll(".article")].forEach((article) =>
    article.classList.remove("hidden")
  );
}
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

/* Roboto Font */

@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i,900,900i&display=swap");
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

button.clear {
  border: 0;
  background: #fff;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.custom__select {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.custom__select-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  user-select: none;
  width: 100%;
}

.custom__select-trigger {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 22px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #3b3b3b;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  background: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.custom__options {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  background-color: #005fec;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-top: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 2;
}

.custom__select.open .custom__options {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  pointer-events: all;
  color: #fff;
}

.custom__option {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 22px 0 28px;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.custom__option:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #b2b2b2;
}

.custom__option.selected {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.custom__option.selected::before {
  content: "•";
  margin-left: -12px;
  padding-right: 8px;
}


/* arrow */

.arrow {
  position: relative;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
}

.arrow::before,
.arrow::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 0.15rem;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.arrow::before {
  left: -5px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background-color: #394a6d;
}

.arrow::after {
  left: 5px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  background-color: #394a6d;
}

.open .arrow::before {
  left: -5px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.open .arrow::after {
  left: 5px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.arrow::after {
  left: 5px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  background-color: #394a6d;
}

.open .arrow::before {
  left: -5px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.open .arrow::after {
  left: 5px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="custom__select-wrapper">
    <div class="custom__select">
      <div class="custom__select-trigger">
        <span>Story Type</span>
        <div class="arrow"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="custom__options" id="storyFilter">
        <span class="custom__option selected">All</span>
        <span class="custom__option" data-value="news">News and Media</span>
        <span class="custom__option" data-value="analysis">Analysis</span>
        <span class="custom__option" data-value="press">Press Releases</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="custom__select-wrapper">
    <div class="custom__select">
      <div class="custom__select-trigger"><span>Year</span>
        <div class="arrow"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="custom__options" id="yearFilter">
        <span class="custom__option selected">All</span>
        <span class="custom__option" data-year="2020">2020</span>
        <span class="custom__option" data-year="2019">2019</span>
        <span class="custom__option" data-year="2018">2018</span>
        <span class="custom__option" data-year="2017">2017</span>
        <span class="custom__option" data-year="2016">2016</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- reset button -->
<button class="clear hidden" id="selectedFilter" onclick="clearSelection()">clear filters</button>

<!-- articles -->
<div class="list article" data-year="2020" data-story="news">
  <ul>
    <li><strong>Company:</strong> Company 1</li>
    <li><strong>Start Date:</strong> March 26, 2020</li>
    <li><strong>Title:</strong> <a href="#" target="_blank">Article Title</a></li>
    <li><strong>Type:</strong> news</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="list article" data-year="2019" data-story="news">
  <ul>
    <li><strong>Company:</strong> Company 2</li>
    <li><strong>Start Date:</strong> November 17, 2019</li>
    <li><strong>Title:</strong> <a href="#" target="_blank">Article Title</a></li>
    <li><strong>Type:</strong> news</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="list article" data-year="2018" data-story="analysis">
  <ul>
    <li><strong>Company:</strong> Company 3</li>
    <li><strong>Start Date:</strong> March 15, 2018</li>
    <li><strong>Title:</strong> <a href="#" target="_blank">Article Title</a></li>
    <li><strong>Type:</strong> analysis</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="list article" data-year="2017" data-story="analysis">
  <ul>
    <li><strong>Company:</strong> Company 4</li>
    <li><strong>Start Date:</strong> January 3, 2017</li>
    <li><strong>Title:</strong> <a href="#" target="_blank">Article Title</a></li>
    <li><strong>Type:</strong> analysis</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="list article" data-year="2016" data-story="press">
  <ul>
    <li><strong>Company:</strong> Company 5</li>
    <li><strong>Start Date:</strong> March 13, 2016</li>
    <li><strong>Title:</strong> <a href="#" target="_blank">Aritcle Title</a></li>
    <li><strong>Type:</strong> press</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="list article" data-year="2015" data-story="press">
  <ul>
    <li><strong>Company:</strong> Company 6</li>
    <li><strong>Start Date:</strong> March 6, 2015</li>
    <li><strong>Title:</strong> <a href="#" target="_blank">Article Title</a></li>
    <li><strong>Type:</strong> press</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Any thoughts on the reset button?

Comment: I did not see any buttons. Did you mean selecting All in the options?

Comment: It's in the HTML. The goal was that if an option from the dropdown is selected, then a "Clear Filters" button would display. Otherwise, it will have the class `.hidden` attached to it.

Comment: Ah. Well the eventListener was a change. It should be click.

Comment: Copy that! Thanks... It's the little things.